# Proving Finite Union of Disjoint Closed Intervals is Closed?

Tags: real-analysis, recreational-mathematics

Forgive my poor LaTeX, I'm very new to it (as in, reading guides as I go just to write this).

In my Elementary Real Analysis course, we're asked to prove a finite union of closed sets is itself closed. I've already done it using de Morgan's law with the complement of a finite intersection of open sets; however, I got to thinking about how I would go about proving it in the specific case of pairwise disjoint closed intervals without de Morgans. I know that if the unions themselves form a new interval, then we can just create a 'ball':
$$
\ A \subset \mathbb R^n\,.  
\forall r>0\,,  \alpha=\inf{A}\,, \gamma=\sup{A}\,,\,\, B(\alpha,r) \not\subset{A}\  and\, B(\gamma,r) \not\subset{A}
$$
Where $\alpha$ is the minimum of the infima of all the intervals, and $\gamma$ is the max of the suprema of all the intervals.

And so I was wondering how the argument would look if the intervals were all disjoint? I tagged it as recreational since, while it is related to my studies, is more for me than anything else.

Also, forgive me if this has been answered; I looked around at many different questions that seemed similar enough, but didn't find one that had asked this precisely.

Comment: Don't you want $A\subseteq {\cal P}(\Bbb R)$, $A$ finite? $A\subset\Bbb R^n$ suggests it is a subset of $n$-dimensional space, which is not what you want.

Comment: You're probably right, I think I wrote $\mathbb R^n$ because I was thinking of the ball, but it should have just been the real line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose the intervals are $[x_1,y_1],[x_2,y_2],\dots,[x_n,y_n]$, ordered so that $x_1\le y_1<x_2\le y_2<\dots<x_n\le y_n$. Then the complement of $\bigcup_{k=1}^n[x_k,y_k]$ is

$$(-\infty,x_1)\cup(y_1,x_2)\cup(y_2,x_3)\cup\dots\cup(y_{n-1},x_n)\cup(y_n,\infty),$$

and each open interval is open: the bounded ones can be written as $(a,b)=B(\frac{a+b}2,\frac{a-b}2)$ and the unbounded ones can be written in terms of bounded intervals as $(-\infty,x_1)=\bigcup_{z<x_1}(z,x_1)$ and $(y_n,\infty)=\bigcup_{z>y_n}(y_n,z)$. Thus a finite disjoint union of closed intervals has a complement which is a union of open balls in $\Bbb R$, and so is closed by definition.

Comment: Perfect! Thank you very much. So in a way it's still sort of like de Morgan's, as in when you've taken the intersection of all the complements, it ends up being the union as you wrote it there.